# How to convert my code to with or wherehas eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**My code works perfectly but, I need to convert it to with or wherehas eloquent. How to convert this code to with or wherehas eloquent? Please help me find a solution. Thanks**

**This is the format of my code that I want to convert to with or wherehas eloquent:**

```
    if($progname == null && $sy_from == null)
    {
        $filter = DB::table('curricula_lists as curricula_list')
        ->join('curricula as curriculum','curriculum.id','=','curricula_list.curriculum_id')
        ->join('programs as program','program.id','=','curricula_list.program_id')
        ->select([
            'curricula_list.id as curricula_id',
            'curriculum.id as curriculum_id',
            'program.id as program_id',
            'program.program_no',
            'program.program_name',
            'program.program_code',
            'program.program_status',
            'curriculum.effective_school_year_from',
            'curriculum.effective_school_year_to',
            'curriculum.scheme'   
            ]);

        return $filter->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    }
    else{
        $tbl = DB::table('curricula_lists as curricula_list')
        ->join('curricula as curriculum','curriculum.id','=','curricula_list.curriculum_id')
        ->join('programs as program','program.id','=','curricula_list.program_id')
        ->select([
            'curricula_list.id as curricula_id',
            'curriculum.id as curriculum_id',
            'program.id as program_id',
            'program.program_no',
            'program.program_name',
            'program.program_code',
            'program.program_status',
            'curriculum.effective_school_year_from',
            'curriculum.effective_school_year_to',
            'curriculum.scheme'   
            ]);

        if(!empty($progname))
        {
            $tbl = $tbl->where('program.program_name',$progname);
        }

        if(!empty($sy_from))
        {
            $tbl = $tbl->whereBetween('curriculum.effective_school_year_from',array($sy_from,$sy_to));
        }

        return $tbl->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    }
```

**I try this eloquent code but the result is different from what I'm expecting**

```
 if($progname == null && $sy_from == null)
    {
        return CurriculaLists::with('Curriculum','Program')->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    }
    else{
        return CurriculaLists::whereHas('Curriculum',function( $query ) use($sy_from,$sy_to){
            $query->whereBetween('effective_school_year_from',array($sy_from,$sy_to));
        })->orwhereHas('Program', function ( $query ) use($progname){
            $query->where('program_name',$progname);
        })->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    }
```

Comment: even using join() is a part of eloquent, what do you want is not clear

Comment: ah I see, I just want to convert my code using wherehas or with, I try but their result is different. I want to get the result the same as the code with DB query and left join. can you help me, sir? @bhucho

Comment: like this, is this valid? 

``else{
      $tbl = CurriculaLists::with('Curriculum','Program');    
      if(!empty($progname))         
       {      
       $tbl = $tbl->where('program.program_name',$progname);         
       }          
      if(!empty($sy_from))        
      {          
       $tbl = $tbl-   
    >whereBetween('curriculum.effective_school_year_from',array($sy_from,$sy_to));         
      }          
     return $tbl->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
}``

Answer (score 0):

I want to help too, I will post my answer here since my problem is resolved. You can use this code for filtering some column for example where program_name or where between year_from,year_to.

```
    if($progname == null && $sy_from == null)
    {
        return CurriculaLists::with('Curriculum','Program')->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    }
    else{
        $tbl = CurriculaLists::with(['Curriculum','Program']);

        if(!empty($sy_from))
        {
            $tbl = $tbl->whereHas('Curriculum',function( $query ) use($sy_from,$sy_to){
                $query->whereBetween('effective_school_year_from',array($sy_from,$sy_to));
            });
        }

        if(!empty($progname))
        {
            $tbl = $tbl->whereHas('Program', function ( $query ) use($progname){
                $query->where('program_name',$progname);
            });
        }
          return $tbl->skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    }
```